# Getting an iPhoto book project created on an iPhone to another device like a Mac or iPad

Tags: iphone, photos.app, ios

I can't find an option for exporting my iPhoto book project off my iPhone. I tried looking for a share option, I've checked iCloud to see if it is saved there, I looked in photo streams. I'm hesitant to spend $30 on a book from my iphone without checking resolution on a larger screen.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into this as well. As of this time (March 2014) there is no way to export an iphoto book created on an iphone or ipad other than to automatically send it in for printing with the associated cost. Hopefully they will come up with a way to export these as a pdf file the way they have done with the desktop version of iphoto.